# pfSense OpenVPN from specific IPs and Anywhere

Tags: openvpn, pfsense

I have 4 Openvpn users, but i would like to restrict the 3 of them to allow connect through the VPN only from specific IPs and the 4th from anywhere. Anyone knows how can i do that?

I thought about a second OpenVPN instance, but i wanted to know if i can accomplish it with only one openvpn instance.

Also i tried to accomplish it with Access list on the WAN interface (public vpn endpoint) but i think you can't do that because of the rules.

Comment: What if the first instance is for 3 users with dynamic ips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve it with 2 VPN instances (is the only solution). The 1st instance is for the 3 users in port e.g 11944 that i wanted to have Access from static IP addresses. Then i made an alias and added the 3 static ip addresses of the VPN users, to be more easy to import one rule from them `From: alias to: 11944 - Allow`.

After this i made a 2nd OpenVPN instance to another port e.g 11945 and leave it open `From: Any to 11945` so everyone can connect to this VPN instance (of course it's TLS/User Auth). Then i made another rule for blocking `From: Any To: Any` and done!

Cheers.